# Display polygon in react-mapbox-gl

Tags: javascript, reactjs, polygon, geojson, mapbox-gl

I'm using this package https://github.com/alex3165/react-mapbox-gl in my app.
I would like to display polygons but when I do that this way:

```
console.log("Display polygon");

let polygonPaint = MapboxGL.FillPaint = {
    'fill-color': "#ff0000",
    'fill-opacity': 0.3
}

<Layer key={"polygonKey"} type="fill" paint={polygonPaint}>
    <Feature coordinates={
            [[[-67.13734351262877, 45.137451890638886],
            [-66.96466, 44.8097],
            [-68.03252, 44.3252],
            [-69.06, 43.98],
            [-70.11617, 43.68405],
            [-70.64573401557249, 43.090083319667144],
            [-70.75102474636725, 43.08003225358635],
            [-70.79761105007827, 43.21973948828747],
            [-70.98176001655037, 43.36789581966826],
            [-70.94416541205806, 43.46633942318431],
            [-71.08482, 45.3052400000002],
            [-70.6600225491012, 45.46022288673396],
            [-70.30495378282376, 45.914794623389355],
            [-70.00014034695016, 46.69317088478567],
            [-69.23708614772835, 47.44777598732787],
            [-68.90478084987546, 47.184794623394396],
            [-68.23430497910454, 47.35462921812177],
            [-67.79035274928509, 47.066248887716995],
            [-67.79141211614706, 45.702585354182816],
            [-67.13734351262877, 45.137451890638886]]]
       }/>
 </Layer>
```

Then rendering loops... :/ and render again and again the same polygons. I've tried with GeoJSONLayer circles, Markers and only `<Layer>` causes this problem.
So there is my question if I can display polygons in GeoJSONLayer? I can see that mapbox provide something like this (https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/geojson-polygon/) but I don't know how to do that in React package.

Answer (score 8):

OK I've done it. Data object should have type: "**FeatureCollection**", and then geometry object should have type "Polygon". GeoJSONLayer need "fillPaint" object to display beautiful polygons ;)
My code:
geojson object

```
{  
   type: "FeatureCollection",
   features: [{
      "type": "Feature",
       "properties": {
             "category": cat,
           },
       "geometry": {
             "type": "Polygon",
              "coordinates": [[
                  [-67.13734351262877, 45.137451890638886],
                  [-66.96466, 44.8097],
                  [-68.03252, 44.3252],
                  [-69.06, 43.98],
                  [-70.11617, 43.68405],
                  [-70.64573401557249, 43.090083319667144],
                  [-70.75102474636725, 43.08003225358635],
                  [-70.79761105007827, 43.21973948828747],
                  [-70.98176001655037, 43.36789581966826],
                  [-70.94416541205806, 43.46633942318431],
                  [-71.08482, 45.3052400000002],
                  [-70.6600225491012, 45.46022288673396],
                  [-70.30495378282376, 45.914794623389355],
                  [-70.00014034695016, 46.69317088478567],
                  [-69.23708614772835, 47.44777598732787],
                  [-68.90478084987546, 47.184794623394396],
                  [-68.23430497910454, 47.35462921812177],
                  [-67.79035274928509, 47.066248887716995],
                  [-67.79141211614706, 45.702585354182816],
                  [-67.13734351262877, 45.137451890638886]
                ]]
        }
   }]
}
```

And GeoJSONLayer component usage

```
<GeoJSONLayer
   key={index}
   data={geojsonObject}
   fillPaint={polygonPaint}
/>
```

I hope that it will be useful for someone :)

Comment: Hi @skylinr I dont suppose you have a git gist of this do you? Currently also trying to find a working example of polygons with this pkg.

Comment: Unfortunately i don't have. But what is Your problem there? Because in my case main problem was that I did not set type as "FeatureCollection"  :) with second "type" setted as "Feature"

Comment: Ah thanks for coming back to me - i actually got it working in the end. Broke everything out into separate packages and went through slowly. Got there in the end. Thank you anyway. @Skylinr

Answer (score 1):

In the current react-mapbox-gl version(5.1.0), the straightforward solution worked for me:

```
<Layer
  type="fill"
  paint={{
    "fill-color": "#0091cd",
    "fill-opacity": 0.2,
  }}
>
  <Feature
    coordinates={myPolygonCoordinates}
  />
</Layer>
```